# Angular 7, persistent database without connection

Tags: database, angular, angular7, persistent

I am trying to create an application that can be used in 2 ways:

1) As a web application, on the browser

2) As a standalone desktop application (for all platforms)

My problem is the data storage in the second case (I need some data storage that is not related to the session). And I need an embedded database, to make the application autoinstallable.

For the first option, I have no problem. I will make rest calls and a backend in something like Spring or others.

For the second option, I am looking over the web but I cannot find a nice solution. I need that the standalone app can work without internet connection. I saw:

- NeDB (that was good for my case), but I am having some troubles with Angular 7 integration. And then I saw that latest release is 3 years ago.
- Pouchdb, but is in session storage, then you have to connect to Couchdb  or others to make it persistent.
- SQLite solves the issue. But is not real time.
- I thought also about a solution with .DBF files.

What is the best solution?